# Using SendGrid package with C# "Web" as shown in examples, is undefined

Tags: c#, sendgrid

The code I'm using looks just like so many examples
But "Web" is an undefined type.
Even ReSharper can't tell me where to find it.
Do I need another reference with a using or has 'Web' been renamed in v 9.9.0?

```
var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
            myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
            myMessage.From = new EmailAddress("somebody@xyz.com", "Fff  
Lll");
            myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
            myMessage.PlainTextContent = message.Body;
            myMessage.HtmlContent = message.Body;

            var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
            );

            // Create a Web transport for sending email.
            var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);
```

Comment: you are using an old version of SDK. in 9.9.0 you have to use the V3 api and `SendGrid.Helpers.Mail, SendGrid.` namespaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are following the V2 api documentation which is now obsolete . You can use the V3 api SDK instead . The sample code is like below

```
            var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY");
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
            var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
            var to = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
            var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
            var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

you need to refer the below namespaces

```
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
```

you can also send the mail without the mail helper class . Follow the below link for more usage and demo

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/USE_CASES.md

Nuget link :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!